# passing objects to a class in java

Tags: java, oop, javafx, webview

I am using webview in JavaFx and in my app I have several panels which I would like to embed a browser window onto. I am struggling with the object oriented bit. Can you see what I need to do differently.

In my main program I have this for one panel:

```
            JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            browser browser = new browser(jPanel);
            browser.setVisible(true);
            browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
```

I get a red underline on the second line.

In my browser class:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class browser extends JFrame {

    private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    private WebEngine engine;
    //private final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());


    public browser(object panel) {
        super();
        initComponents();
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        createScene();

        panel.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        getContentPane().add(panel);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();

    }

    private void createScene() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {

                WebView view = new WebView();
                engine = view.getEngine();


                jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadURL(final String url) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                String tmp = toURL(url);

                if (tmp == null) {
                    tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
                }

                engine.load(tmp);
            }
        });
    }

    private static String toURL(String str) {
        try {
            return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
                return null;
        }
    }


}
```

I get a red underline where it says Object and also wherever it says panel.

Comment: I don't see you doing anything with the parameter in your constructor, and I'm pretty sure that Object in java is capitalized.

Comment: Uppercase `Object`. Also, there's no sense in having that parameter there in the constructor when you don't use it? You never assign to another variable. And you probably want a more explicit type than `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: What is `object` and why do you pass it to the constructor. If you want to use object like "superclass of all classes" object, it's upper case: `Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public browser(object panel)
```

Your variable `panel` could well be an object, but the class object is defined as `Object`, not `object`. Causing the "red line" A.K.A. a compiler error.

The reason you also get a compiler error on panel, is because they're not visible within your other methods. You pass your object `panel` into the constructor, but it is never set within the class. E.g. making a class-wide variable like:

```
private Object panel;
public browser(Object panel) {
    super();
    initComponents();
    this.panel = panel;
}
```

That will allow your panel object to be seen in the entire class.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. This managed to get the job done. If I could give everyone a like I would.